# How to create google sheet with public access enabled using programming

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a google sheet with public access enabled using PHP. At this moment, I am generating the google sheet for the newly inserted code. User can download the google sheet.

But now I want to give a default permission public to dynamically created google sheet via code. Is it possible in google sheet?

Here is a code

```
// Creating new spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = new Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet([
    'properties' => [
        'title' => "$sheet_name"
    ]
]);
$spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->create($spreadsheet, [
    'fields' => 'spreadsheetId'
]);
$sheet_id = $spreadsheet->spreadsheetId;

//End Creating new spreadsheet
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your issue correctly, are your asking to how change sharing permissions programatically?

Comment: @ziganotschka yes,

Answer (score 1):

- For creating permissions programmatically you need the method [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)
- Once you have the `sheet_id`, create a permission with `permissions->insert()`
- Specify the role as desired (e.g. `reader`, `writer`,...)
- For pulib availability of the file - specify the type as `anyone`

Sample how to implement it in php:

```
$newPermission= new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission->setType('anyone');
$newPermission->setRole('reader');
$service->permissions->insert($sheet_id,$newPermission);
```

Comment: First of all thanks @ziganotschka I have tried the above code, but my code google sheet code stopped working

Comment: What do you mean by `stopped working`? Obviously, what I showed in the sample is only a snippet to be incorporated into the code you already have - including authorization flow etc. You might also need to update your scopes - hard t say since I did not see your full code.

Comment: Please have a look, Here is my code, https://pastebin.com/WDybGvXQ

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Your code incorporates only the scope "Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS", while the creation of permissions requires the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` - as specified in the documentation of the method.

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to change line 17 in your code from `$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);` to `$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS,Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);`

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to use an API key to make changes to a sheet.  The answer is you cant.

You need to have authenticated access either though Oauth2 or a service account. using one of the below scopes to make any changes with an API.

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Public sheet just means anyone can download and see it and probably make changes via the Sheets web applicaition.   Changing it with the API requires access.

You can create a sheet then use the google drive api to update the [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) on the sheet to make it public but again thats not going to enable you to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to set/change permissions of the file. This code can update the permissions of the google spreadsheet too.
I have spent a lot of time. So, anyone who is finding it hard to get any solution to make the google spreadsheet public/any_permission, you can refer to this code.
You can further refer to [Google Drive API v3 permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create).

```
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $permission->setRole( 'reader' );
    $permission->setType( 'anyone' );
    $service->permissions->create( $spreadsheetId, $permission );
```